# Algorithm to multiply two matrices given their inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-complexity

I have seen a number of places in literature claim that the complexity of multiplying two nxn matrices is equivalent to the complexity of being able to take their inverse. (assuming square invertible matrices of course)

While one part of that seems clear and well documented on the internet (how to use a fast multiplication algorithm to get the inverse at equivalent speed), I am having trouble understanding why the reverse of that is true. (ie given two matrices and their inverses or an algorithm that can quickly compute the inverse find the product efficiently)

Is there a known algorithm that allows one to quickly compute the product of two matrices when their inverses are known?

Comment: If I understand your question, I would think it is the same time complexity as it would be given just two ordinary matrices with their inverses unknown. That is, with the algorithms we have for matrix multiplication such as Strassen's to name just one. But, one deep in research in numerical methods might have deeper insight.

Comment: I can interpret the first paragraph and the question in the third paragraph is clear. However, the second paragraph is not clear to me. What is known and available and what must be computed? What are the restrictions on what we are allowed to do? If you have $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ and you want $AB$, why it it not enough to use that $$AB=(B^{-1} A^{-1})^{-1}$$ or $$AB=(A^{-1})^{-1} (B^{-1})^{-1}.$$

Comment: My question is around the computational complexity of finding the product given A and B and their inverses. The answer you gave implies the naive solution that requires at least one direct matrix multiplication (ie O(n^3)) My question is whether or not its possible to compute AB faster than known matrix multiplication algorithms given that you are supplied the inverses or with an algorithm that finds the inverses quickly.

Comment: "The answer you gave implies the naive solution that requires at least one direct matrix multiplication". No, it does not. Strassen's algorithm is still available.

Comment: I think I am not being clear here: My question is "does knowing the inverses mean there is a way to compute AB faster than using any of the known matrix multiplication methods?". Strassen's is a matrix multiplication algorithm, I am trying to understand if its possible to do this faster than Strassens/coppersmith-winograd/etc.